# How can I add Disk io to Nagios monitoring system?

Tags: nagios

Here is my htop view and I am not seeing any disk io, but I only can see memory, CPU and swap. How can I implement disk io too?

[image]

Comment: htop have no connection with Nagios. If you need monitor your io, then you must use some Nagios plugin. For example [link](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_iostat--2D-I-2FO-statistics/details) or [link](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/Check-IO-stats-of-one-or-all-disks/details).

Comment: Yup I know that there is no link between htop and Nagios this was just for showing.